# Where is data coming from on this web page?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am trying to scrape data from this website in R.

https://keeptradecut.com/dynasty-rankings/players/patrick-mahomes-272

Specifically, I am trying to scrape "All-time" dynasty value below:

[image]

I was able to successfully scrape historical dynasty value data from this page: https://keeptradecut.com/dynasty-rankings

By going to the Network tab and finding the XHR request "history". Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be an equivalent request on this page. It feels like it should be there because the data has to be coming from somewhere. Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

The data is on the original html page, not obtained via xhr. It is buried in a json object inside a script tag.

If we look at the all time plot for the page you linked, we get this:

[image]

And we can get this data ourselves by doing:

```r
dat = "https://keeptradecut.com/dynasty-rankings/players/patrick-mahomes-272" |>
  httr::GET() |> 
  httr::content("text") |> 
  strsplit("overallValue\":") |>
  getElement(1) |>
  getElement(2) |>
  strsplit("],") |>
  getElement(1) |>
  getElement(1) |>
  paste0("]") |>
  jsonlite::parse_json() |>
  lapply(as.data.frame) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows() |>
  within(Date <- as.Date(d)) |>
  within(Value <- as.numeric(v)) |>
  dplyr::select(Date, Value)
```

This results in

```
head(dat)
#>         Date Value
#> 1 2020-05-26  9999
#> 2 2020-05-27  9999
#> 3 2020-05-28  9974
#> 4 2020-05-29  9995
#> 5 2020-05-30  9999
#> 6 2020-05-31  9991
```

We can see this is right by plotting:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(Date, Value)) +
  geom_area(fill = "#cfeaf9", color = "#4fb4e9", linewidth = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(7500, 10100)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's amazing! How did you know to look there? I guess from a process standpoint, should the flow be to check XHR requests and then try a GET request? Any resources you'd recommend? Sorry, I only ask all this bc my knowledge on web scraping and related topics is pretty cobbled together.

Comment: In most cases you'll end up with the correct request in no time if you focus on Search in (Chrome) network tab. I.e pick some less common value from the chart, in this case searching for "9257"  would return just 2 suspects, both from the page source, one in `var playerSuperflex` and the other in `var playerOneQB`. PrettyPrint the Response view and/or search for the same value in Response and time series are easy to spot. Though there's no one single strategy, e.g. not all js chart libraries use absolute values for storing series data.

Comment: @dkro23 usually dynamic web pages get their data from json via an xhr request, so I usually snoop in the console first. If I don’t find the data there, then it must be on the actual html page that the browser first requests when navigating to the page. This is usually too big to review in the R console, so I usually download the page to memory and paste it into a text editor. Then I can scroll around looking for json. I work out how the json string can be stripped out with regex in R then parse with a json reader.

Comment: @dkro23 I don’t know of any resources that detail the intricacies of web scraping in R. I have learned via trial and error, working on several scraping projects, and of course from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @margusl: I think it would be helpful for future readers to add what you wrote about your strategy for identifying the data source to the body of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to tracking down actual data sources, be it for charts or any other dynamic content, my personal first stop is the Search on Network pane of browser's Developer tools. This targets most common methods of dynamic content delivery (API responses with JSON and XML content, embedded javascript, tables in HTML comments, partial page updates from Ajax calls). When choosing a search term, it helps when it's not too common, for example some extreme value that is present on just a few charts. So let's pick "9257", in Chrome it would look something like this:
[image: Search on a Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools]

From there we have located not just the most probable request but also few locations in the content that we should focus on:
`var playerSuperflex` at line 82 and `var playerOneQB` at 83.

While For JSON responses the *Preview* tab is preferred, for HTML & mixed content *Response* tab with Search and Pretty Print ( `{}` ) provides a better overview of embedded Javascript and stored values.

From the page source we have identified that `playerSuperflex` and `playerOneQB` are global variables, thus directly accessible through *Source > Watch* or *Console* to get a better idea of what we are facing and which parts we would like access in R:
[image: playerSuperflex in Dev Tools Console]

Though there's no single strategy and simple search through Network results can sometimes fail too, for example some JS charting libraries use differential values (change from previous data point) so looking for some abloute constant might not work out; or data is exchanged in some binary format like protobuf.

---

Couple of "lazy" aproaches once the data source is identified:
throw as much as possible (right side of `playerSuperflex` assignment) to `jsonlite` and extract the required bit from parsed results; or evaluate the whole script with V8 Javascript Engine first and then get the `playerSuperflex.overallValue` js object.

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# First, etract relevant `<script>` element with rvest & XPath
html <- read_html("https://keeptradecut.com/dynasty-rankings/players/patrick-mahomes-272")
js <- html %>% 
  html_element(xpath = "//script[contains(., 'playerSuperflex')]") %>% 
  html_text()

# extract right side of relevant assignment from script, 
# parse it as JSON and get series data:
overallValue <- js %>% 
  # regex with lookahead and lookbehind, extract text between 
  # "var playerSuperflex =" and next ";"
  stringr::str_extract("(?<=var playerSuperflex =)[^;]+(?=;)") %>% 
  jsonlite::parse_json(simplifyVector = T) %>% 
  getElement("overallValue")
tibble(overallValue)
#> # A tibble: 1,125 × 2
#>    d              v
#>    <chr>      <int>
#>  1 2020-05-26  9999
#>  2 2020-05-27  9999
#>  3 2020-05-28  9974
#>  4 2020-05-29  9995
#>  5 2020-05-30  9999
#>  6 2020-05-31  9991
#>  7 2020-06-01  9999
#>  8 2020-06-02  9999
#>  9 2020-06-03  9996
#> 10 2020-06-04  9977
#> # ℹ 1,115 more rows
```

```r
# OR evaluate the whole script with V8 and extract 
# playerSuperflex.overallValue JS object:
ctx <- V8::v8()
ctx$eval(js)
overallValue_v8 <- ctx$get("playerSuperflex.overallValue")
tibble(overallValue_v8)
#> # A tibble: 1,125 × 2
#>    d              v
#>    <chr>      <int>
#>  1 2020-05-26  9999
#>  2 2020-05-27  9999
#>  3 2020-05-28  9974
#>  4 2020-05-29  9995
#>  5 2020-05-30  9999
#>  6 2020-05-31  9991
#>  7 2020-06-01  9999
#>  8 2020-06-02  9999
#>  9 2020-06-03  9996
#> 10 2020-06-04  9977
#> # ℹ 1,115 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

And another low-effort approach with Chromote. Though in this case it's just overkill, instead of a single request it makes around 300 and generates 10x more traffic (~ 3.8MB). Still, assuming that we do know that we would just need to access a global variable, having Chromte to handle the request, render the page and evaluate a tiny bit of javascript for us can be compelling at times:

```r
library(chromote)
b <- ChromoteSession$new()
{
  b$Page$navigate("https://keeptradecut.com/dynasty-rankings/players/patrick-mahomes-272")
  b$Page$loadEventFired()
}
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 792152
b$Runtime$evaluate("JSON.stringify(playerSuperflex.overallValue)")$result$value |> 
  jsonlite::fromJSON() |>
  tibble::tibble()
#> # A tibble: 1,125 × 2
#>    d              v
#>    <chr>      <int>
#>  1 2020-05-26  9999
#>  2 2020-05-27  9999
#>  3 2020-05-28  9974
#>  4 2020-05-29  9995
#>  5 2020-05-30  9999
#>  6 2020-05-31  9991
#>  7 2020-06-01  9999
#>  8 2020-06-02  9999
#>  9 2020-06-03  9996
#> 10 2020-06-04  9977
#> # ℹ 1,115 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I've been scraping with R for ages, but this contains a couple of cool tricks I haven't used before. Thanks a lot for posting.