# webscrape table from website in r using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape the EUR swap rates from https://sebgroup.com/our-offering/prospectuses-and-downloads/rates/swap-rates

There are already a lot of questions and answers about such scraping issues, but unfortunately none of them attemps were helping here. So please provide me a hint to this specific problem.

I tried to use the table class directly or the div class in various versions, like

```
url <- paste0("https://sebgroup.com/our-offering/prospectuses-and-downloads/rates/swap-rates/")
xml2::read_html(url) %>%  
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath="//div[@class='overflow-auto table-container']") 

xml2::read_html(url) %>%
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath="//table[@class='table text-nowrap w-100 mb-6']")
```

but the reply is always {xml_nodeset (0)}

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table content is not included in the page source but fetched by Javascript running in your browser. When inspecting elements through browser's dev tools, that DOM tree might not reflect what's available for `rvest`, it can be heavily modified by Javascript, while `rvest` can only work with actual page source. To check the source, choose *"View page source"* instead of "Inspect" in page's context menu (Chrome) or navigate to `view-source:https://sebgroup.com/our-offering/prospectuses-and-downloads/rates/swap-rates` . Or disable Javascript for a particular page, refresh and inspect.

Or better yet, save and explore that exact content that is loaded by `rvest` as it can still be quite different compared to the content delivered to your browser:

```r
rvest::read_html(url) %>% xml2::write_html("page.html")
```

So, in this particular case, instead of working with page source, we can make those same API calls ourselves and work with returned JSON response:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# transform a list of tables, ex:
# [[1]]
#        value align tooltip decimals valueType clickValue
# 1       1 Yr  <NA>      NA       NA      <NA>         NA
# 2       4.26 right      NA        2      <NA>         NA
# 3      -0.04 right      NA        2      diff         NA
# 4      11:41 right      NA       NA      <NA>         NA
# 5 2023-08-31 right      NA       NA      <NA>         NA
# 
# [[2]]
#        value align tooltip decimals valueType clickValue
# 1       2 Yr  <NA>      NA       NA      <NA>         NA
# 2       3.99 right      NA        2      <NA>         NA
# 3      -0.05 right      NA        2      diff         NA
# 4      11:41 right      NA       NA      <NA>         NA
# 5 2023-08-31 right      NA       NA      <NA>         NA

# , to a single table 
format_cur_data <- function(d){
  tibble(data = d) %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
    unnest(data) %>% 
    mutate(name = c( "maturity", "price", "diff", "time", "date"), .by = row) %>% 
    select(row, name, value) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
} 

rates_api <- "https://sebgroup.com/ssc/trading/fx-rates-bff/api/rates/swap?currency="

# cycle thrrough list of currencies,
# request swap rates,
# extract table content from response and 
# and call format_cur_data()
c("SEK", "NOK") %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(\(cur) paste0(rates_api, cur)) %>% 
  map(jsonlite::fromJSON) %>% 
  map(list("rows", "data")) %>% 
  map(format_cur_data)
```

Results for *SEK* and *NOK* :

```r
#> $SEK
#> # A tibble: 14 × 6
#>      row maturity price diff  time  date      
#>    <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#>  1     1 1 Yr     4.26  -0.04 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  2     2 2 Yr     3.99  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  3     3 3 Yr     3.75  -0.06 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  4     4 4 Yr     3.57  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  5     5 5 Yr     3.44  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  6     6 6 Yr     3.36  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  7     7 7 Yr     3.31  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  8     8 8 Yr     3.27  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#>  9     9 9 Yr     3.24  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#> 10    10 10 Yr    3.23  -0.05 12:16 2023-08-31
#> 11    11 12 Yr    3.21  0     12:16 2023-08-31
#> 12    12 15 Yr    3.18  0     12:16 2023-08-31
#> 13    13 20 Yr    3.08  0     12:16 2023-08-31
#> 14    14 30 Yr    2.81  0     12:16 2023-08-31
#> 
#> $NOK
#> # A tibble: 12 × 6
#>      row maturity price diff  time  date      
#>    <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#>  1     1 1 Yr     5.02  3.16  12:15 2023-08-31
#>  2     2 2 Yr     4.95  2.36  12:15 2023-08-31
#>  3     3 3 Yr     4.7   1.84  12:15 2023-08-31
#>  4     4 4 Yr     4.51  1.56  12:15 2023-08-31
#>  5     5 5 Yr     4.38  1.4   12:15 2023-08-31
#>  6     6 6 Yr     4.28  1.3   12:15 2023-08-31
#>  7     7 7 Yr     4.21  1.23  12:15 2023-08-31
#>  8     8 8 Yr     4.15  1.18  12:15 2023-08-31
#>  9     9 9 Yr     4.11  1.14  12:15 2023-08-31
#> 10    10 10 Yr    4.07  1.12  12:15 2023-08-31
#> 11    11 12 Yr    3.99  1.08  12:15 2023-08-31
#> 12    12 15 Yr    3.88  1.05  12:15 2023-08-31
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's just perfect @margusl, thanks a lot!! I still would like to ask where you got the address of the api call from? If I go through your explanations I end up on SEB's developer site but can't find a matching url. Do you still have the link? Thanks again

Comment: @Christian , I extracted that endpoint from calls that were triggered by javascript, through network tab of browser's dev tool. I and many others have some answers with more detailed explanations of scraping strategies that often deal with working with a network tab, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76538104/646761 .  Handful of others - [rvest network* api*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5brvest%5d%20network*%20api*&searchOn=3)

Comment: got it! Learned a lot! I will have a look on your link. Thanks